# Ruby on Rails - rails g scaffold foreign key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

Im new to ruby and I want ot create database with table User, Role and user Role. And my question is should I use scaffold or something else? And how to add autoincrement id in this tables? And how to add foreign key?

```
rails g scaffold User name:string surname:string  && rails generate scaffold Role name:string id:integer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I use scaffold or something else?

You can use a scaffold, if what you need is all the files and changes in your project related to that specific table/model. A scaffold will add assets, models, controllers, and even tests. If you feel you don't need it, you can create a single migration which can handle the table creation in your database and that's all. If in the other hand, you need more than that, you can create a model (`rails g model ...`), and so on, and so forth.

> And how to add autoincrement id in this tables?

By convention, Rails will add an `id` column in your table, unless specified otherwise. Depending on your database, it'll will use the `AUTO INCREMENT` clause, or a `SERIAL` if using Postgres. As it supports multiple relational database management systems, there are a lot of options for that.

> And how to add foreign key?

When creating a scaffold, or a model, or a migration, you can use the `references` option. In your case If you have a User and UserRole models/tables, it'd look like this:

```
rails g scaffold User name && rails g scaffold UserRole user:references
```

You can check the [Rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) about migrations for further information.

---

Complement for the given question:

```
class ... < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :... do |t|
      t.references :user_id_rated, references: :users, foreign_key: true
      t.references :rated_by_user_id, references: :users, foreign_key: true
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you. Can you tell one more thing? I want one user to be assigned to rate another user. So I need table with userid, userid2, ratings: rails g scaffold User name && rails g scaffold UserReview ratings:integer user:references user2:references.

Comment: Sure, in that case your columns would be like `rate_user_id`, `rated_by_user_id`, you'd have to create the migration, with placeholder values through the rails command and then modify it as you need in the migration file, see the updated answer @VMG.